# Updating hostnames in netfilter automatically?

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

I'd like to accomplish an egress filter on Linux using Netfilter (iptables) and the DNS hostname of the destination. The problem is, writing the rules using the hostname will only resolove the IP addresses when the rules are loaded.

To further complicate the matter, if the destination is load balanced or redirects to a cluster, these IP addresses are not allowed egress.

For instance, If I add an allowed egress rule for a Ubuntu package repo such as:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d packages.project.org -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT`

Netfilter will add several IPs such as `packages.project.org.herokudns.com` which  resolve to something like 34.x.x.x, 35.x.x.x, 44.x.x.x, 38.x.x.x

when I perform an `apt update` on this host, it fails with:
`100% [Connecting to project-package-repository.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (51.xxx.xxx.xxx)]` and is quickly blocked.

Is there a way to make Netfilter see this destinations as "allowed" when connecting to the original repo?

Comment: For me, `packages.project.org` resolves to the single IP address `206.188.192.100`. No matter which root server(s) I use, that seems to be the only address I'm offered

Comment: Use ipset or dedicated chain that can be flushed and replaced regularly.

Comment: Also apt does make use of SRV entries in DNS (contrary to a web browser) to complicate things, but packages.project.org doesn't have such entry.

Comment: @A.B - Have tried the dedicated chain route updated via cron in the past and just always felt there must be a better way to do it. I've never used ipset. I'll look into that. Thanks. @roaima - `packages.project.org` was just an example. Probably didn't need to be redacted but just a habit.

Comment: consider this dns answer: `dig _http._tcp.deb.debian.org. -t srv` => `_http._tcp.deb.debian.org. 294 IN SRV 10 1 80 debian.map.fastlydns.net` . In some cases the final IP result with -t srv might differ from the result of `dig some.debian.url -t a` (or -t aaaa).

Comment: @A.B any suggestions on the better tool for resolving these hostnames in your example? `dig` has multiline output which makes scripting from it difficult. `host` gives single line output, but not sure it's as full featured as `dig`. `nslookup` and `whois` get even trickier - at least in my experience.

Comment: No real idea beside dig and host. Anyway you'd be better served by a proxy rather than by a firewall. See for example: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/apt-cacher-ng . The proxy should be provided full internet access then (and none needed for the system(s) updating through it)

Comment: @A.B - thanks for the info. You are right about having a local apt cache. It's so much faster updating 60+ hosts during a short maintenance window. I am trying to solve the egress filtering problem though and apply the automated rule update to many hosts. I've tried `bash` for this sort of task in the past and it always gets ugly when finally nailed down. Really surprised there isn't a tool out there for this already.